# Cleaning web text using readLines and the tm-package in R

Tags: r, url, nlp, tm, readlines

I am trying to remove regex codes and numbers on a webpage using the `readLines` function. I am using the `unlist` function for some of this. However, I'm not sure how to remove numbers. I was thinking of using the `tm-package`, but I seem to be missing a format conversion. How can I transform my webpage to remove numbers etc. with tm, or is there an easier way of removing redundancy from the text? I hope to concatenate a number of webpages to be read, so it will be quite a bit of cleaning.

```r
 library(rvest)
 library(tm)
 webpage <- readLines("https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2020/02/200219113746.htm", 
             encoding = "UCS-2LE")
 dirtytext <- unlist(strsplit(webpage,"\\r|\\n|\\t"))
 cleantext <- tm_map(dirtytext,removeNumbers)
```

The last line gives the error message:

> 'Error in UseMethod("tm_map", x) : 
>     no applicable method for 'tm_map' applied to an object of class "character"'

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to remove html tags?  It's not a good idea to read in the raw page and then try to clean it up instead of using a package designed for parsing web content.  You've loaded `rvest`, why not use it?

Comment: What kind of text information are you looking for?

Comment: H-1, thank you. It's more than html tags that needs to be cleaned. I couldn't get the rvest to work so ended up using readLines. But you're probably right. I'll give rvest another try. jazzurro, I need the main text to run frequency, association, sentiment etc on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to include the lede but the following returns the story by paragraph (which removes all the non-story elements contained in the text like advertising).

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2020/02/200219113746.htm"

page <- read_html(url)

story <- page %>%
  html_nodes("div#text p") %>%  # use "div#story_text p" to include lede
  html_text
```

Comment: Thank you so much H 1, it works! I wasn't familiar with pipes and didn't fully understand the html_nodes function, but it should work well now.

Comment: I tried again with a webpage without the .htm-extension and this turned out with no text (character: 0). Not sure if I should use a different package for that or look for a solution in the rvest package?

Comment: You should stay with `rvest`.  It's not a one-size fits all task.  Different pages can have different structures and will need different selectors to parse.  You may want to post a new question if you're having issues determining the correct selectors.